# Get content of a div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-select

```
<select>     
<div class="options">
              <option value="nothing">Nothing</option>
              <option value="snothing">Second Nothing</option>
      </div>
</select>
```

I want to get the content of the DIV and print it inside javascript in a selector.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var options = $('.options').html();
.
.
.
        var content = '<select>' + options + '</select>';
.
.
.

    });
```

I need to take options from the HTML. I've created a div indise `<select></select>` tags, because I had no other idea. But it's not working! 
I tried to put the options var inside `<p></p>` tags so i can print it, it sais 'undefined'.

Comment: You can't put a `div` as a direct child of a `select`.

Comment: T.J. is correct. Remove the div, place the options class on the select instead and it will work.

Comment: Could you try and explain a little more clearly what you're trying to achieve? Whatever it is, poorly formed HTML will not be the answer.

Comment: But I need to get ONLY the `<option>content</option>`, without `<select>` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the missing `>` is a typo, your structure is invalid. `select` elements [cannot have `div` elements as direct children](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-select-element).

You *could* do this:

```
<select class="options">
    <option value="nothing">Nothing</option>
    <option value="snothing">Second Nothing</option>
</select>
```

And then

```
var options = $('.options').html();
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/osumal/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/osumal/1/edit)

Comment: So how do you suggest to get ONLY the options inside the `select` ?

Comment: @Sergiu: Use a valid structure?

Comment: This is the accepted answer. Thank you! I have to wait 5 more minutes before marking it as accepted, but I will.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, remove the `<div>`. It's not helping you at all. Then, if you want just the options:

```
$("select").html(); // to get the HTML
```

or

```
var something = $("select options"); // to get an array of jQuery objects
```

Answer (score -1):

What you want, I think, is: `$('select').html(options)` or `$('select').append(options)`
where options is an html string, e.g. `"<option value='1'>One</option>"`, or a jquery element collection e.g. `$('option')`.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the inline code elements, didn't know you could do that (I'm new here). Down vote seems harsh since my explanation should help him, but oh well.